# Unable to download the windows update using script

Tags: vbscript, windows-update

I am running Windows 2015 LTSB and use below script to download the Windows patches as and when required.
Previously the below script use to work from normal user, but from past few days it just shows the message as

> Download completed successfully. Please press any key to continue.

Where actually nothing is downloaded and this script doesn't go to install updates.
And when I execute the same script from user with Admin privileges, it downloads and installs the relevant update packages.

I suspect that `downloader.Download()` is behaving differently for Admin and Normal user.

Can you please assist me in knowing what is the cause of updates not getting downloaded from normal user.

```
Option Explicit
Dim updateSession, updateSearcher, update, searchResult, downloader, updatesToDownload, updatesToInstall, installer, installationResult, InputKey, i, endKey

If Right((LCase(WScript.FullName)),11) <> "cscript.exe" Then
    WScript.Echo "Please carry out this script using CSCRIPT.EXE." & _
        vbCrLf & "Example: cscript WindowsUpdate.vbs"
    WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "Please press any key to continue."
    endKey = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    WScript.Quit(0)
End If
Dim strInp
On Error Resume Next
WScript.Echo "Press Enter key to begin Windows Update."
strInp = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine

WScript.Echo "------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "Windows Update"
WScript.Echo "------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "Verifying latest update..."
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()
Set searchResult = _
    updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and AutoSelectOnWebSites=1")
'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
If IsNull(searchResult.Updates.Count) Or IsEmpty(searchResult.Updates.Count) Then
    WScript.Echo "An error occurred. Please check your network connection and try again."
    WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "Please press any key to continue."
    endKey = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'Err.Clear
    WScript.Quit(0)
End If

For i = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
    WScript.Echo i + 1 & vbTab & update.Title & " Size: " & update.MaxDownloadSize
Next

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Windows is up to date."
    WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "Please press any key to continue."
    endKey = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    WScript.Quit(0)
Else
    WScript.Echo "A newer version of " & searchResult.Updates.Count & _
        " is found. Downloading starts."
End If

WScript.StdOut.Write "Preparing download..."
Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")
For i = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
    WScript.StdOut.Write "."
    updatesToDownload.Add(update)
Next

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Newer version of programs is downloading..."
Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
downloader.Download()
'WScript.Echo "DEBUG [downloader.Download().ResultCode]:" & downloader.Download().ResultCode

If downloader.Download().ResultCode = 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Download completed successfully."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Download failed."
End If
If downloader.Download().ResultCode = 4 Then
    WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "Please press any key to continue."
    endKey = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    WScript.Quit(0)
End If

WScript.Echo "Download the following programs is successfully completed."
For i = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
    If update.IsDownloaded Then
        WScript.Echo i + 1 & vbTab & update.Title
    End If
Next

Set updatesToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")
WScript.StdOut.Write "Preparing installation..." 
For i = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
    If update.IsDownloaded = True Then
        WScript.StdOut.Write "."
        updatesToInstall.Add(update) 
    End If
Next

'WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "DEBUG [updatesToInstall.Count]:" & updatesToInstall.Count
If updatesToInstall.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Installation failed."
    WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "Please press any key to continue."
    endKey = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    WScript.Quit(0)
End If

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Installing..."
Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
Set installationResult = installer.Install()

If installationResult.ResultCode = 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Installation completed successfully."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Installation failed."
End If
WScript.Echo "Detail information."
For i = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
    WScript.StdOut.Write i + 1 & vbTab & _
        updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title
    If installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode = 2 then
        WScript.Echo "Succeed."
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Failure."
    End If
Next

'WScript.StdOut.Write "Restart is required."
If installationResult.RebootRequired Then
    'WScript.Echo "Required."
    WScript.Echo "Computer restart is required to complete installation."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Computer restart is not required."
End If

WScript.StdOut.Write vbCrLf & "Please press any key to continue."
InputKey = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
If installationResult.RebootRequired Then
    Dim objWshShell
    Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objWshShell.Run "%comspec% /c shutdown /r /t 0", 0, False
    WScript.Quit(-1)
Else
    WScript.Quit(0)
End If
```

Comment: If the same code worked before, but doesn't work now, then clearly something about the system must have been changed. You need to investigate that.

Comment: Hi @Ansgar, systems are quite hardened and nothing is changed on them except for windows updated being installed from time to time. I am suspecting some change in behavior of downloading updates, so also verified that the windows download folder permissions are unchanged.

Comment: After debugging i have found that the downloader.Download() is behaving differently for Administrator and Standard user, and is returning null for Standard user.